# Multiple forms interaction in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two pages ,let's say `page1.aspx` and `page2.aspx` . What i'm going to do is ,in `page1.aspx` i made a call to `page2.aspx` with `window.open()` javascript and pass the querystring ,and in `page2.aspx` (child page) ,I need to collect some information from user and after submitting ,I need to pass all the collected data to `page1.aspx` (parent page) ,what is the solution for this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature called [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) but it is designed to communicate from the page that fires a popup to the popup and not the other way around (also it isn't supported by IE Mobile (incase that matters)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored in database, reload the page1 after page2 submit using javascript. Otherwise store data in session and reload.